# How to fix this?? Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

Sup guys, im working on level system in roblox studio. So i find a funny error when i spent all stats points and level up me added not 4 points but so many points like i didnt spend anything

Here the script:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", Player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local lvl = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    lvl.Name = "Level"
    lvl.Value = 1
    
    local exp = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    exp.Name = "Exp"
    exp.Value = 0
    
    local reqexp = Instance.new("NumberValue", Player)
    reqexp.Name = "reqexp"
    reqexp.Value = lvl.Value * 100
    
    local hp = Instance.new("NumberValue", Player)
    hp.Name = "Health"
    hp.Value = 100
    
    local points = Instance.new("NumberValue", Player)
    points.Name = "Points"
    points.Value = 0
    
    exp.Changed:Connect(function(Changed)
        if exp.Value >= reqexp.Value then
            points.Value += 4
            exp.Value = 0
            lvl.Value += 1
            reqexp.Value = lvl.Value * 100
        end
    end)
    
    
end)
```

I tried many ways but nothing help

Comment: I don't think your error is in this code. Where is your code that spends the points? And is that code a LocalScript?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Kylaaa ServerScriptService, and this one is just script